# WPF in VB: How to get a textBox out of the form from a String?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am trying to obtain the object TextBox in my WPF form from a String where the String is equal to the TextBox.Name

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Window>
<DockPanel>
<TabItem Header="3">
<Grid>
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox2"/>
</Grid>
</TabItem>
</Dockpanel>
</Window>
```

In VB i made this function which isn't working

```
Private Function getTextboxOutName(ByVal parent As DependencyObject, ByVal textBoxName As String) As Object
    Dim element As Object

    Dim aantalElementen As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
    If aantalElementen > 0 Then
        For n As Integer = 0 To aantalElementen - 1
            Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, n)
            element = child
            If element.Name = textBoxName Then
                Return element
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use the textbox name to access it in code?

Comment: Please, can you describe a scenario where you need to use this kind of function?

Comment: I have 8 textBoxes and 8 Strings where I want to randomly place 1 String in one textBox. So random int i would give me textBox(i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the elements from the code behind with the name you gave them.

Or if you still want to enumerate the tree, you should use a recursive approach to find the element. The msdn shows folliwing example [msdn VisualTreeHelper.GetChildCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchildrencount(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
     Public Shared Sub EnumVisual(ByVal myVisual As Visual)
        For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual) - 1
            ' Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
            Dim childVisual As Visual = CType(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i), Visual)

            ' Do processing of the child visual object.

            ' Enumerate children of the child visual object.
            EnumVisual(childVisual)
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thank you, is there also a way to convert a 'visual' into an element like a textBox?

Comment: Dim x = TryCast(visual, TextBox), returns null if it is not a textBox